# How to change levels in Julia

Tags: julia

I want to change the levles of a vector, but I don't know how to do it in julia.

My julia version is 1.1, and my code:

```
Sire = ["ZA","AD","BB","AD","AD","CC","CC","AD","AD"]
levels(Sire)
levels(Sire) = [1,2,3,4]
```

Wrong message:

```
julia> levels(Sire) = [1,2,3,4]
ERROR: error in method definition: function Missings.levels must be explicitly imported to be extended
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

Comment: I make a summary:

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use CategoricalArrays.jl package to work with categorical data (if you need more information about it please comment and I can give you more information).

If you work with a standard `Vector` you can use `replace` function like this:

```
julia> Sire = ["ZA","AD","BB","AD","AD","CC","CC","AD","AD"]
9-element Array{String,1}:
 "ZA"
 "AD"
 "BB"
 "AD"
 "AD"
 "CC"
 "CC"
 "AD"
 "AD"

julia> l = unique(Sire)
4-element Array{String,1}:
 "ZA"
 "AD"
 "BB"
 "CC"

julia> replace(Sire, Pair.(l, axes(l, 1))...)
9-element Array{Any,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 2
 2
 4
 4
 2
 2
```

or you could do the last step manually:

```
julia> replace(Sire, "ZA"=>1, "AD"=>2, "BB"=>3, "CC"=>4)
9-element Array{Any,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 2
 2
 4
 4
 2
 2
```

Note that `unique` returns values in their order of appearance. If you want a specific order you should change `l` accordingly (e.g. `sort!` it).

Answer (score 0):

I make a summary:

```
Sire = ["ZA","AD","BB","AD","AD","CC","CC","AD","AD"]

# methods 1
a1 = deepcopy(Sire)
new = collect(1:length(levels(Sire)))
d = Dict(zip(levels(a1),new))
using CategoricalArrays
re1 = recode(a1,d...)

# methods 2
a2 = deepcopy(Sire)
new = collect(1:length(levels(Sire)))
un = unique(a2)
replace(a2, Pair.(un, axes(un, 1))...)


# methods 3
a3 = deepcopy(Sire)
new = collect(1:length(levels(a3)))
d = Dict(zip(levels(a3),new))
re3 = replace(a3,d...)
```